# printing out words from textfile -bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a textfile details.txt
that have details of itemId,itemName,itemQuantity

```
details.txt
1,egg,20
2,meat,40
```

firstly I will request the user to input the item name and if the input of the item name matches with the item name found in text file , it will print out the quantity for the item.

e.g 
Enter item name:egg

output

```
Quantity
20
```

below is what I have but it's not working as I don't know how to achieve my expected output. Please advise thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName="details.txt"

read -p "Enter item name" itemName
if grep -q $itemName $fileName; then
  echo "Quantity"
  awk '{print $4}' $fileName
else 
  echo "No Record Found"
fi
```

my output

```
Quantity
20
40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the "field separator" to a comma. In this case, since you're displaying the entire contents of the second field, `awk` is overkill; you can use

```
grep $itemname $filename | cut -d, -f3
```

If you want to use `awk`, you need to print only matching lines:

```
awk -F, "/$itemname/ { print \$3 }"
```

Note, in this case, that you need use use double-quotes so the value of `$itemname` will be passed to `awk`, and you'll need to escape the `\$3` so it *won't* be interpreted by the shell before passing the argument to `awk`. I'd stick with `cut`.  :-)

You can store the output as a variable by using the syntax `var=$(`*`command`*`)` like this:

```
output=$(grep $itemname $filename | cut -d, -f3)
```

Comment: sorry one more question. is it possible to store the command      grep $itemname $filename | cut -d, -f3 into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code, `grep` *tests* whether the file contains the item at all, and then `awk` prints out the quantity of *all items in turn*, which of course is incorrect.

So one way to do it would be to grep again

```
grep $itemName $fileName|awk '{print $4}' $fileName
```

Comment: thanks for your help but however if you do                        grep $itemName $fileName|awk '{print $4}' $fileName  it will still print all the value in column 4 of the text file